# Is it possible to change the fractal value outside of the subdivide panel? (blender 2.9)

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, subdivision-surface

I have a mesh that I subdivided, and increased the fractal amount on it.  Now I am later in the project, and I want to increase the fractal amount even more, but I don't want to subdivide it again.  Is there any way to change the fractal amount without subdividing the mesh again?  any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: I was also wondering, I don't know if it exists, but you can go in the header menu > Select > Select Random, then scale, or use a Displace modifier?

Comment: yea, I guess I could do that, it would just be more helpful if the fractal value was readily available